# If Then to un-protect and protect document

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, userform

I have a userform that unprotects a document to let info be entered then protects the document. All of my subs work aside one.

Ranges with if/thens don't work but basic if then works.

Example of sub that works:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password"
    Dim ComboBox5 As Range
    Set ComboBox5 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmragpd").Range
    ComboBox5.Text = Me.ComboBox5.Value
    
    If Me.ComboBox5.Value = "No" Then
        ComboBox5.Text = "205.55a"
    End If
    
    If Me.ComboBox5.Value = "Yes" Then
        ComboBox5.Text = ""
    End If
    ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:="password"
End Sub
```

This sub will say the document is already unprotected.

I tried removing the unprotect on combobox6:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox6_Change()
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password"

    Dim rngComboBox6 As Range
    Dim sssaText As String
    Dim iiia As Integer

    Set rngComboBox6 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmfcs").Range

    sssaText = ComboBox6.Value

    If Me.ComboBox6.Value = "Yes" Then

        For iiia = 1 To 1

            sssaText = sssaText & Chr(13) & "200" _
              & Chr(13) & "200.1" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "OEBS" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "21c" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "22c" _
              & Chr(13) & "Yes" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "Yes" _
              & Chr(13) & "Two" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "ES2a.1" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "222" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "222a" _
              & Chr(13) & "222b" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "3.a.1" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "NA" _
              & Chr(13) & "" _
              & Chr(13) & "I. TuuVa"
 
        Next iiia

        sssaText = sssaText & Chr(13) & "717217" _
          & Chr(13) & "" _
          & Chr(13) & "1212" _
          & Chr(13) & "" _
          & Chr(13) & "D.1" _
          & Chr(13) & "F2B-4"

    End If
            
    rngComboBox6.Text = sssaText

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "bmfcs", rngComboBox6
    
    If Me.ComboBox6.Value = "No" Then
        ComboBox6.Text = ""
    End If
    
    ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:="password"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `End If` is in the wrong place. You are adding text to the document regardless of the value of the combo box.

It is not good practice to use a control’s change event to commit changes to a document. Apart from anything else it doesn’t allow the user to cancel without making changes.

Instead use an OK/Apply/Finish button.

Then you only need to unprotect/reprotect the document once.